# Can I add project refer a .net framework dll in .net core project.If yes where should I refer the dependency dll

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I have a .net framework(4.5.2) project.I need to refer the .net framework dll in .net core(6.0) project .I have added the framework dll in core solution by adding the dll through project reference.Now I have also added the dependency dll in same location .But when I debug I get can error
"System.ServiceModel" reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution,they can only be loaded in reflection-only loader context

I have tried moving the system dll in the location of the framework dll ,but still facing the same error